# In shell, how to I use output of one command as input parameter to another

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two git commands

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags/<<XX>>
```

I want output from first command to be used as substution for <> in second command. So far i'm writing the output of first command in a file and then using it in second.

Just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: `git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` this is called command substitution

Comment: More verbosely, you can assign the result of a command to a variable like this `var=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` , so by surrounding it with `$(...)` and you can use the value of the variable with `$var` making your second command: `git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags/$var`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

respectively

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags/`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the former notation can be used ala Matryoshka doll (command substitution inside command substitution) whereas the latter can't (or not easily).